# Unable to take control over MSIX updates for .net 6 WinForms application

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0, auto-update, msix

I am trying to build MSIX setup for my WinForms application built on .net6. I want to give auto-update feature when the user clicks the "Update" button. I think originally developer didn't have control over updating MSIX and there was only way it was updated automatically when the application is restarted.

But there is a recent article on taking full [control over MSIX updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/getting-full-control-over-msix-updates-with-the-app-installer/ba-p/3371344) I tried to follow it but I am facing the exception 'System.InvalidOperationException' while running the below line of code.

```
Package package = Package.Current;
```

I am using visual studio 2022 & WinForms application running on .net 6. I have kept other configurations as described in the above article but it is not working as expected. (I have tried in .net core 3.1 and it is working with it)

Comment: Also checked & followed related Microsoft document, but there is no luck - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/non-store-developer-updates#add-the-packagemanagement-capability-to-your-package-manifest

Comment: Are you actually debugging your app in a packaged context? Are you launching the packaging project? I think an InvalidOperationException is the expected result if you are calling from an unpackaged process.

Comment: @marv51 Thank you for your response. Yes, I was running it in debug mode with visual studio. It worked after I published it as a package and installed on the machine. However, It is a bit difficult to debug it this way. I am still facing issue while updating application. when I click update button it simply closes and not updating application. Is there any way to debug app in packaged context?

Comment: Did you follow these steps to setup the packaging? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

After that, right click the packaging project and choose "Set as Startup Project". Now you can run/debug normally.

Comment: @marv51 I was able to debug it by choosing Packaging project as "Set as Startup Project". thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: So if you choose the Packaging project as "Set as Startup Project" the Package.Current crash is gone?

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, feel free to accept that answer as correct if your problem was solved this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Package.Current` only works in a packaged context, so you need to make sure to actually debug/launch the packaging project. An `InvalidOperationException` indicates that you are running your project unpackaged.

Make sure to select "Set as Startup Project" on the packaging project, likely named "MyApp (Packaging)" in the Solution Explorer. Then you can launch/debug your project as you normally do.